# EF 4.1 Code Only?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

As far as I can tell (correct me if I'm wrong), there are two main approaches to using Entity Framework:

1. Model First: start with a predefined database and let EF create the code for you.
2. Code First: write the code, and let EF create the database for you.

I have an existing database and I'd like to write the code myself.  Is this "Code Only" approach supported?  Does such an approach even make sense in the context of EF?

Comment: it could be me, but I can't see the question here?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat:  I don't want EF to generate either the database or the code for me.  Is there a way to do the mapping manually?

Comment: if EF is generating neither, then you don't need EF

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I'd like to use EF as an ORM tool so that I can program against my business objects and let EF handle querying and updating the db.  I've used Linq-to-SQL in this fashion and it works well.

Comment: @MCS: then you have a choice of (1) OR (2) listed above.

Comment: I just came across a post (http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/model-first-database-first-or-code-first-ndash-update-to-data-points-column/) by Julie Lerman where she discusses what to do when someone has both a preexisting database and preexisting classes.  She suggests using Code First.  I don't understand why.

Comment: @MCS: She suggests Code First in this case because you can (somewhat) easily write code to map your existing classes to the database schema, and thereby avoid having to totally throw out all the classes you've already defined. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with most of the other answers. From what I've seen, the EF "Code First" technology is really just a way to define your model using conventions, annotations, or a fluent mapping definition, rather than an EDMX file. If you write your "Code First" files to mirror your database schema, there is no reason that Entity Framework would be unable to produce the appropriate queries and statements using LINQ to Entities.

For more information, see Scott Guthrie's post on [Using EF "Code First" with an existing database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx).

Comment: I actually remember coming across that article before, not understanding the point of creating "Code First" (or Code Second?) on an existing database.  It looks like all he did was hand-code the same code that could have been generated by a Model First approach.  Of course, he's the Gu, and I'm not questioning the guy that headed EF4.  Rather, just stating that I don't get it.

Comment: @Jerad Rose: I can think of a couple of reasons. First, if somebody wants to reuse classes they'd previously defined, but re-wire their data access layer to take advantage of LINQ to Entities, they could create a "code first" entity context that maps their POCOs to their database's structure. Second, some people just don't like auto-generated code. (Though I personally have no problem with it, when it's used right.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Ok, I can see that.  I'm trying to fit that with the OPs situation, though.  He doesn't have existing classes (states he wants to write the code himself), so maybe he just doesn't like generated code.  I don't know, I'm still having a hard time wrapping my brain around why one would prefer to hand-code entities for an existing database, just for the sake of not having the generated code.  Seems backward-thinking to me.  But to each their own, I guess. :)

Comment: @Jerad Rose: "Ours is not to question why..." ;-)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Touche. And +1, as this does give the OP an option.

Comment: @Jerad Rose: I simply don't like generated code.  Maybe the EF generated code is really super and not bloated at all, but I have found with L2S, web services, etc. that I have an extremely difficult time debugging generated code (or debugging code that uses generated code).  When I write the code myself, I know what's going on, how to debug and how to make optimizations and modifications.  This approach works when the db is small.  I don't know that I would hand-code all the classes if the db contained 100's of tables.

Comment: @MCS - You might consider at least looking at some sample code from EF4 POCO T4 templates.  It's actually fairly light-weight, and you may find it very similar to the code you will end up hand-writing.  As I said, if you're using an ORM, much of the point of it is to save you the duplication of efforts on creating a database & mapping for existing entities, or creating entities & mapping for an existing database.

Comment: I can think of a few more reasons why you would want to use Code First and a manually created database. First, you get full control over the database schema, mapping logic, and entities. Some people here were saying "don't use EF then" - but EF's *primary* goal is ORM, not code generation. Also, EF's "EDMX" designer surface is terrible for any DB with more than about 8 tables or so. It's dead slow, and requires specialized connection strings. It's also hard to unit test. Code first is hard to use in production scenarios where a formal DB release process is required.

Answer (score 2):

[Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) allows you to reverse engineer a database to generate code first like code (that won't re-generate your database).  Then you can tweak it from there as you need.

Comment: Interesting.  What is the difference between this and using the Model First POCO T4 templates?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to decide what your system of reference is -- the code (Code First) or the database (Model First).  If you have an existing database, then go with a Code First approach, it will be hard to keep your changes in synch without generating your model from your code, or your code from your model.

If you have an existing database, but want to extend your model beyond the generated code, you could implement partial classes to accomplish this.

If you want to manually map your EF4 code and your database, you could consider [this approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738546.aspx).  However, this eliminates some of the benefit of an ORM, which is to set up the mapping for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you can't have your cake and eat it too in this case - there has to be **one** definite source on what your model is, it is either the database (DB first), which then generates matching code for you, or the code (Code first) which will then create a matching DB.

Comment: Isn't EF useful as an ORM tool?  Does it have generate either code or DB to be useful?

Comment: The definition of an ORM is that it generates Data Repository plumbing code for you based on some form of model.

Comment: The database can be your one definite source without requiring that your classes be auto-generated from it. @Mitch Wheat: Entity Framework can still handle the data repository plumbing without requiring that your classes be automatically generated from your database model.

Answer (score 1):

The Entity Framework team answered these questions on their blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/07/when-is-code-first-not-code-first.aspx